# How to get different documentation on help() for different objects in python

Tags: python, function

I have a class with help message, which should depends on input argument for `__init__`, e.g.:

```py
class A:
    '''
    {}
    '''
    def __init__(self, x):
        A.__doc__ = A.__doc__.format(x)
```

But when I run

```py
x = A("xxxxx")
y = A("yyyyy")
help(x)
help(y)
```

I get the same messages for both `help()` calls:

```
Help on A in module __main__ object:

class A(builtins.object)
 |  xxxxx
 |
:
```

Is there a way to create different documentation for different objects?

Answer (score 0):

The `__doc__` member that gets used in help is the class' `__doc__`, not the instance's. **That means there can be only one**. See the data model's [special method lookup section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup):

> For custom classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type

I am not familiar with the details, but it also seems the class' `__doc__` property can be set only once. That means you will get the docstring you set in the first instance you create. Perhaps someone will know more about this.

**An alternative?**

So now the question is whether you want a function that *behaves* the way you described. Since you want a different docstring, I suppose you want different behavior for each instance (otherwise why would you want a different docstring?). That might be clearer if you have a collection of derived classes. If this is not the case, it would help to know the specific problem you are trying to solve.

You could then have a factory method that will create objects of the proper type, given the arguments.